# postgres: create table in database from the command line

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I am trying to create a table in postgres, but it ends up in the wrong database.

Here is what I do: in my sql script initially I create a user and a database, and then a table. Code will explain more:

```
drop database if exists sinfonifry;
drop role if exists sinfonifry;

-- create the requested sinfonifry user

create user sinfonifry createdb createuser password 'some_password';

-- create a sinfonifry database
create database sinfonifry owner sinfonifry;

DROP TABLE if exists sinf01_host;

CREATE TABLE sinf01_host
(
  host_id bigserial NOT NULL, -- The primary key
  host_ip inet NOT NULL, -- The IP of the host
  host_name character varying(255) NOT NULL, -- The name of the host
  CONSTRAINT "PK_host" PRIMARY KEY (host_id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

ALTER TABLE sinf01_host OWNER TO sinfonifry;
```

now, this is part an automated script, and is executed from the command line, like:

```
sudo -u postgres psql < create_db.sql
```

and I already have the postgres user created on the system.

And here comes the problem: the table ends up in the postgres database, public schema, not in the sinfonifry database, public schema.

How can I create the table in the database I want to?

Thanks, and cheers, f.

Comment: Connect to the freshly created database before creating any objects in it.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

After the create database command issue a connect:

```
create database sinfonifry owner sinfonifry;
\connect sinfonifry
```